# application crashes at spriteFrameByName in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone

```
[action_array addObject:[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"baloon-bl_%d",i]];
```

How can I solve it

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an error message.

Comment: It works when you use it correctly.Which function needs which argument and how you call that method that make it possible to run your code.otherwise compiler says error in case of syntax and crash if you are using in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are brackets missing. Try:

```
[action_array addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"baloon-bl_%d",i]]];
```